# RUN apk add --update --no-cache py3-arrow not wokring in alpine docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, pyarrow

I have built an image from: https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-$2.4.4/spark-$2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

Once is downloaded, I do:

```py
cd spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7 && bin/docker-image-tool.sh build
```

Then my image `spark-py:latest` is built.

I want to install pyarrow in it using this docker file:

```py
FROM spark-py:latest
COPY *.jar /opt/spark/jars/
RUN rm /opt/spark/jars/kubernetes-*-4.1.2.jar

RUN apk add --no-cache \
            build-base \
            cmake \
            bash \
            boost-dev \
            autoconf \
            zlib-dev \
            flex \
            bison \
            g++ 
           
RUN wget -q https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3 get-pip.py && rm -f get-pip.py
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --update --no-cache py3-arrow
```

but I have an error:

```py
> [8/8] RUN apk add --update --no-cache py3-arrow:
#12 0.552 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#12 1.269 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#12 1.672 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
#12 1.688   py3-arrow (missing):
#12 1.688     required by: world[py3-arrow]
```

The repository is here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86/py3-arrow

I can see that is repository testing but I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This package is located in the [testing repository](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Community_Repository). By default `/etc/apk/repositories` doesn't contain one.

[image]

You could add repo with the `apk add` command.

```
RUN apk add  \
   --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
   --update --no-cache py3-arrow
```

or insert it directly to the end of `/etc/apk/repositories`

```
RUN echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing' >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk add --update --no-cache py3-arrow
```